# KnockoutJs - Pushing to an element in an observable array does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an object (analysisLogData) that I use to generate a table using KnockoutJS. Here's the viewModel containing this object:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.analysisLogData = ko.observableArray();
    self.analysisLogTitle = ko.observable("Warnings")

    self.changeAnalysisLog = function(title) {
         self.analysisLogTitle(title)   
    }

    var data =

    {
        "Warnings": [
            {
                "number": 3002,
                    "description": "There may be a problem with the device you are using if you use the default profile"
            },

            {
                "number": 3001,
                    "description": "There may be a problem with the device you are using if you don't use the default profile"
            }

            ]

        ,
            "Errors": [
            {


                "number": 1000,
                    "description": "No networks are loaded"
            },

            {
                "number": 1002,
                    "description": "No devices are loaded"
            }]




    }


    self.addLog = function (type, content) {
        self.analysisLogData()[type].push(content);
    }

    self.analysisLogData.push(data)


}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

You can see the result here in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/V4r2e/5/

I want to be able to add an error or a warning without losing the warnings or errors already present.

I tried to do the following in the `self.addLog` function:

```
self.addLog = function (type, content) {
        self.analysisLogData()[type].push(content);
    }
```

but it says that it can't push to an undefined object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after playing around in fiddle. I believe that you need to do some changes in how you pushed data in the observable array. But without doing a lot of modification check my solution in this link.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/V4r2e/7/)

```
self.addLog = function (type, content) {

    self.analysisLogData()[0][type].push({
        "number": 1002,
        "description": content
    });
}
```

And data object should be

```
"Warnings": ko.observableArray([........]),
"Errors": ko.observableArray([..........])
```

I did two things

1. Modify Warnings & Errors to be an Observable Array
2. I pushed the data in this **self.analysisLogData()[0][type].push** instead of **self.analysisLogData()[type].push**

Answer (score 0):

`self.analysisLogData()` is an array which contains arrays of Errors/Warnings.

I'm not sure if that's how you want your data structured.

To get the fiddle to work you can replace the addLog function with this:

```
self.addLog = function (type, content) {
        self.analysisLogData()[0][type].push(content);
    }
```

Comment: Yes that is how I want my data structured. When I put your code, I can add an element. However, the table does not get updated : http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/V4r2e/8/

Comment: when you do analysisLogData() with the parans you're inserting into the underlying array, which is generally how you want to do it. But, you have to fire off notifications to let subscribers know that the observable has new data. See http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html. I usually call .valueHasMutated() after pushing to arrays